# How to switch from "Bugs are managed with tasks" to "Bugs are managed with requirements" in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

When we originally set up our projects we chose the "Bugs are managed with tasks" option, but now we want to use the "Bugs are managed with requirements" (or User Stories as they're called in DevOp's Agile template).  How do we change it?

I've looked at the 'Backlog levels' settings for our custom Agile process:

[image: Backlog levels for a custom process in Azure DevOps]

But I can't work out how to move 'Bug' from the 'Other work item types' section to the 'Requirement backlog' section?  There's no ellipsis link to the left of 'Bug' and no way to manually add a new entry at the 'Requirement backlog' level'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good amount of hunting I finally realised the answer was staring me in the face.  The text under the 'Other work item types' heading states (my emphasis):

> Bug work items appear on the requirement backlog or the iteration
>   backlog based on the **team's** setting

I had already looked in the team's settings too, but had somehow missed it.  It can be found at *[your organisation].visualstudio.com/[your project]/_settings/work-team*

[image: Team configuration page showing Working with bugs section in Azure DevOps]